# Gnome Migration Scripts in 17.10

Tags: unity, gnome, scripts, 17.10

So every time my system starts up its tries to execute this script

`/usr/share/session-migration/scripts/unity-gnome-shell-migration.17.10.py`

It seems to be some script that ubuntu planned to run to migrate all the settings and stuff from unity to gnome, however it keeps failing all the time. So I tried to run it manually and it gave me this reason

`Migration prevented as GNOME Shell launchers are modified from defaults`

I have been using gnome for quite a while and so this isn't surprising at all. I just want to know how I stop this script from running on startup so that it stops the apport dialog from showing every time I start my system